# What's the meaning of the lyrics of Disturbed: Believe?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

While my English understanding is literally 8.5/9 (that's my IELTS score) the deeper meaning of this lyrics -- perhaps because it lacks punctuation -- escapes me. Of course I understand the individual pieces but it just doesn't come together to form understandable sentences. To clarify, I am not looking for the philosophical or religious meaning of this lyrics, I am after missing punctuation, missing conjunctions and such and / or a tree of subsentences.

> Believe, when you lie
>   You will never need to recognize yourself
>   To deceive
>   To remove all chance of doubt and be received
>   With your lie
>   The deception is complete when you concede
>   And decide
>   To reject your lives, sacrificed to me

Comment: The syntax is disturbed. Believe me.

Comment: **djna** has given what seems like an obvious parsing or punctuation of the given text. I suggest watching/listening to the band performing the song (live if possible, not a 'music video') to help in interpretation. The way the singer sings the lyrics could also confirm the punctuation.

Comment: On the other hand watching Bon Iver singing Beth/Rest has yet to help me parse that ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one suggestion. It's difficult to be sure of the author's intentions.
My perception is that many modern songs use words for their "sound" and the impression that's made; the lyrics need not conform to formal grammar or logic.

> Believe, when you lie you will never need to recognize yourself.
>
> To deceive, to remove all chance of doubt and be received with your lie.
>
> The deception is complete when you concede, and decide to reject your lives, sacrificed to me

Comment: +1 Yeah, I think that's a rather obvious parsing of the given text.